# Is there a normal human melatonin concentration to light level curve?

Tags: human-biology, sleep, circadian-rhythms

I'm looking for a graph or a curve that would show the **typical concentration of melatonin in blood or saliva for humans over 24 hours**. It would be good to know the photoperiod for the same human as well.

I know that melatonin release is inhibited by blue light, perceived through the retina, with melanopsin being the photopigment that signals suprachiasmic nucleus to suppress melatonin release. This is why it would be great to see melatonin data alongside light exposure data.

Thank you for any hints on where I can find such information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a few samples here: http://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0024320503008142-gr2.gif this shows the nocturnal melatonin peak, which is apparently very important for well being

[image: melatonin concentration curve]
[image]