# Are (baseline) high blood levels of melatonin associated with either circadian rhythm or mood disorders?

Tags: human-biology, metabolism, sleep, circadian-rhythms

(Exogenous) melatonin is administered at night for treatment of circadian rhythm disorders, but melatonin taken during the day is linked with depression.

I would like to know if high blood levels of (endogenous) melatonin (at a steady state, throughout the day) might be linked with mood or sleep disorders (or have any effect at all), or if the body's response to melatonin adjusts accordingly.

I think the answer to [this SE question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5535/is-there-a-normal-human-melatonin-concentration-to-light-level-curve) is related, but I can't find the source using a reverse image search.

Comment: This question isn't fully answered - I found nothing on circadian rhythm disorders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a recent PLoS article that said that none of hypochondriasis, depression, hysteria, psychopathic deviate, masculinity-femininity, psychasthenia, schizophrenia, or social intraversion (on the MMPI-2) "were associated with any melatonin parameter."

However, it does appear that "increases scores of Hypomania and Paranoia were associated with a shorter DLMO-DLMOff interval" (duration of melatonin production).

The only thing that concerns me are the significance and the effect size of the latter two results.  I can't tell whether they corrected for multiple comparisons or not.

Reference:  [Burgess HJ, Fogg LF (2008) Individual Differences in the Amount and Timing of Salivary Melatonin Secretion. PLoS ONE 3(8): e3055. doi:10.1371/journal.pone.0003055](http://ww.plosone.org/article/info%3adoi/10.1371/journal.pone.0003055)